# Who is R' Yisrael in Reishis Chochmah, Shaar Hamitzvos, and how much of שער המצוות is from him?

Tags: jewish-books, rabbis, authorship

In The *Sefer Raishis Chochmah* (written by Rabbi Eliyahu de Vidas  - 16th century), There is a perek (chapter) called פרק המצוות - The Chapter of the Mitzvos.

After his introduction to the *perek Hamitzvos*, The RC writes:

> על המצוות ועשייתן ועיונם חלק **הר"ר ישראל ז"ל** עשרה שערים ע"ז הסדר.
>
> In regard to the mitzvos and their observance and their insights, **R'
>   Yisrael** obm has divided [this into] 19 gates [chapters], in [the
>   following] order:

He then goes on to discuss the 10 gates of the mitzvos.

1) Who is this **הר"ר ישראל ז"ל** R' Yisrael, whom he is citing?

2) Is just the division into these 10 Gates from R' Yisrael, and the following discussion about them is by the author of the *Raishis Chocmah*, Rabbi Eliyahu de Vidas himself, or is all the material which he writes in *Shaar Hamitvos* all from this R' Yisrael?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=5P8tAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%94%D7%A8%22%D7%A8+%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C+%D7%96%22%D7%9C&source=bl&ots=WhsBhsC7qN&sig=o6WL5tnpISRPCRhDlyX9Sbnub34&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMxbjJuoPcAhUrwlQKHfb6DBoQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%A8%22%D7%A8%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%96%22%D7%9C&f=false) book (see footnote), it is [R. Israel Alnaqua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Alnaqua). According to that source, R. Eliyahu de Vidas appended books of R. Israel Alnaqua to the end of *Reishit Ḥochma*. On [this page](https://books.google.com/books?id=5P8tAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%94%D7%A8%22%D7%A8+%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C+%D7%96%22%D7%9C&source=bl&ots=WhsBhsC7qN&sig=o6WL5tnpISRPCRhDlyX9Sbnub34&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMxbjJuoPcAhUrwlQKHfb6DBoQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA&f=false) ("page 12"), it explicitly mentions *perek hamitzvot* as being appended.

This fact is further corroborated by Hyman G. Enelow, in his edition of the Menorat Ha'maor, where he cites the many parallels between RH and MH throughout his prefaces and notes on the latter.

Comment: I was only able to access the books ad page but not the content pages at all **:(**